# 線形リストで循環ループができてしまう

Tags: python

以下のLeetCodeの問題の解法について質問です。
https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-list/description/

上記問題の解法として以下を参考にしております。
https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-list/solutions/29174/python-concise-solution-with-dummy-nodes/?orderBy=most_votes&languageTags=python

```
def partition(self, head, x):
    h1 = l1 = ListNode(0)
    h2 = l2 = ListNode(0)
    while head:
        if head.val < x:
            l1.next = head
            l1 = l1.next
        else:
            l2.next = head
            l2 = l2.next
        head = head.next
    l2.next = None
    l1.next = h2.next
    return h1.next
```

上記コードのwhileループ直後の`l2.next = None`をコメントアウトすると戻り値が循環ループになってしまうのですが、その理由がわかりません。
例えば、例題

```
head = [1,4,3,2,5,2], x = 3
```

では、1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2, 4...のような無限に続くリストが返ってきます。
`l2.next = None`なしでは循環ループが発生する理由を教えてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whileループ終了時、`l1`は一番最後の`val=2`のノードを指しています。
一方で`l2`は最後から2番めの`val=5`のノードを指しています
この`val=5`の`next`、すなわち`l2.next`は一番最後の`val=2`のノードつまり`l1`を指しています。

whileループ終了後、`l1`は`h2.next`(`val`が3以上の一番最初のノード)につなぎますので、`l2`が`l1`につながったままだとループします。

Comment: わかりやすく教えていただきありがとうございます。原因が理解できました。